# How to write the project roles and responsibilities in Resume for the creation of university web portal?

Tags: resume

I am a team member of our university web portal creation, where I worked in creating a database and interactive web pages with HTML, Javascript , JQuery, Ajax and PHP. But I have not involved in CSS design part. Now I want to write my contribution in my resume, but I do not know how to write it. I need all your helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this from the perspective of what roles did you play in the project:

1. Business Analysis - Did you gather any requirements? Did you clarify anything that had to be done?
2. Solution Architecture - Did you play a role in mapping out the solution and what technologies would be used? Did you test out possible alternative stacks?
3. Development work - This would be the actual implementation work you did.
4. Testing - Did you do any Quality Assurance, unit tests and so forth?
5. Deployment and Maintenance - Did you put this into production or have tasks around promoting the code through various environments?

What were the specific tasks you did, with what technologies and over what time frame would be how I'd frame this for the resume and job interview as chances are this will be something to discuss at that point.

Comment: Mostly i have done all those what you mentioned above except the designing part. Even now i don't know how to mention this in my resume. Will you please help me.

Comment: Sir need your help in writing my resume.

Comment: I've answered your question but I'm not going to write your resume for you unless you are going to pay me a million dollars and then I might consider it.

Comment: @user27487 you just need to list the project and then the roles you performed, like this answer already says.

Answer (score 3):

> Backend + Frontend Developer for a web portal with SQL/PHP/jQuery (no CSS design experience)

Unless you did any of the things JB King mentions to a larger extent, that should cover it pretty well and people know what experience to expect when they hire you.

Replace SQL with the database you used, Postgres, MySQL, Mongo, even the SQL ones are all different in syntax, etc.